# Pandas: how to construct DataFrame with specified types using new nullable string and int types?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create a DataFrame with [new nullable scalar types](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#missing-data-na). I'm using pandas 1.0.3.

Given imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict
```

If I have column names:

```
headers = ['field',
 'yr_code',
 'start_col',
 'end_col',
 'year',
 'variable_name',
 'characteristics',
 'source',
 'date_on']
```

and datatypes:

```
dt = [pd.StringDtype(),
 pd.Int64Dtype(),
 np.int16,
 np.numpy.int16,
 pd.Int64Dtype(),
 pd.StringDtype(),
 pd.StringDtype(),
 pd.StringDtype(),
 pd.StringDtype()]
```

I have tried creating columns specifications as:

```
columns = OrderedDict((h, dt[i]) for i, h in enumerate(headers))
```

And a data frame as (with example data):

```
data = [['F00001', pd.NA, 1, 1, '', 'Blank', '', pd.NA, pd.NA]]     
f = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columns)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work:

```
>>> f.dtypes
field              object
yr_code            object
start_col           int64
end_col             int64
year               object
variable_name      object
characteristics    object
source             object
date_on            object
dtype: object
```

I understand that `dtypes` might be returning underlying types, but surely `yr_code` as object is wrong. How can I create the DataFrame properly for these types?

Answer (score 0):

You can do `f.convert_dtypes()` to get:

```
>>> f.convert_dtypes().dtypes
field              string
yr_code            object
start_col           Int64
end_col             Int64
year               string
variable_name      string
characteristics    string
source             object
date_on            object
```

Comment: Hmm... those aren't the types I specified, though.